# UnsatisfiableError while installing Miniconda

Tags: python, linux, installation, anaconda, miniconda

I wanted to reinstall Miniconda. I have first removed the entire Miniconda install directory, edited the bashrc file to remove the Miniconda directory from the PATH environment, and removed the hidden condarc file and conda folder from the home directory.

Then, I downloaded Miniconda from https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh, and tried to install it with `bash Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh`.

Doing this, I got the following UnsatisfiableError:

```
Unpacking payload ...
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done                                                                     
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                        

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package xz conflicts for:
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
xz==5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.5,<6.0a0']

Package sqlite conflicts for:
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> sqlite[version='>=3.35.4,<4.0a0']

Package ncurses conflicts for:
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_1
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
readline==8.1=h27cfd23_0 -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0']

Package openssl conflicts for:
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> cryptography[version='>=2.8'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
openssl==1.1.1k=h27cfd23_0
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a']

Package tzdata conflicts for:
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> tzdata
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tzdata
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tzdata
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> tzdata
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> tzdata
tzdata==2021a=h52ac0ba_0
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> tzdata
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tzdata
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> tzdata
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tzdata
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tzdata

Package urllib3 conflicts for:
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> requests[version='>=2.18.4,<3'] -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.27']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.27']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> setuptools
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> setuptools[version='>=31.0.1']

Package tk conflicts for:
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
tk==8.6.10=hbc83047_0
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
xz==5.2.5=h7b6447c_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
readline==8.1=h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
_openmp_mutex==4.5=1_gnu -> _libgcc_mutex==0.1=main
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
libgomp==9.3.0=h5101ec6_17 -> _libgcc_mutex==0.1=main
openssl==1.1.1k=h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
libgcc-ng==9.3.0=h5101ec6_17 -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
_libgcc_mutex==0.1=main
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> libgcc-ng -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
tk==8.6.10=hbc83047_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
yaml==0.2.5=h7b6447c_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
libffi==3.3=he6710b0_2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]

Package certifi conflicts for:
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> certifi[version='>=2016.9.26']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.9.26']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> requests[version='>=2.18.4,<3'] -> certifi[version='>=2016.9.26|>=2017.4.17']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> certifi
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.27'] -> certifi
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> certifi[version='>=2017.4.17']

Package ld_impl_linux-64 conflicts for:
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ld_impl_linux-64
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ld_impl_linux-64
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ld_impl_linux-64
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> ld_impl_linux-64
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
ld_impl_linux-64==2.35.1=h7274673_9
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> ld_impl_linux-64
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> ld_impl_linux-64
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> ld_impl_linux-64
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> ld_impl_linux-64

Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
libffi==3.3=he6710b0_2 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_1 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
readline==8.1=h27cfd23_0 -> ncurses[version='>=6.2,<7.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0|>=7.5.0']
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
libstdcxx-ng==9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> libffi[version='>=3.3,<3.4.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.5.0']

Package cffi conflicts for:
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> cffi[version='>=1.12']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> brotlipy[version='>=0.6.0'] -> cffi[version='>=1.0.0|>=1.12']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> cffi[version='>=1.0.0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> cryptography[version='>=2.8'] -> cffi[version='>=1.12']

Package readline conflicts for:
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
readline==8.1=h27cfd23_0
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0']

Package python conflicts for:
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> wheel -> python
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> brotlipy[version='>=0.6.0'] -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> certifi[version='>=2017.4.17'] -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> pyopenssl[version='>=16.2.0'] -> python
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> cryptography[version='>=2.8'] -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> six -> python[version='>=2.7']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> pycparser -> python
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Package zlib conflicts for:
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
pip==21.1.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
tqdm==4.61.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=2.7'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
certifi==2021.5.30=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
wheel==0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
tk==8.6.10=hbc83047_0 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
pycparser==2.20=py_2 -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
idna==2.10=pyhd3eb1b0_0 -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
urllib3==1.26.6=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<4.0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

.
.
.
.
.

Package pycosat conflicts for:
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> pycosat[version='>=0.6.3']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0

Package requests conflicts for:
conda==4.10.3=py39h06a4308_0 -> requests[version='>=2.18.4,<3']
requests==2.25.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.12=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.12=0
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> libgcc-ng -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libffi==3.3=he6710b0_2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libgcc-ng==9.3.0=h5101ec6_17 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - libstdcxx-ng==9.3.0=hd4cf53a_17 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ncurses==6.2=he6710b0_1 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - openssl==1.1.1k=h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - readline==8.1=h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - sqlite==3.36.0=hc218d9a_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - tk==8.6.10=hbc83047_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xz==5.2.5=h7b6447c_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - yaml==0.2.5=h7b6447c_0 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zlib==1.2.11=h7b6447c_3 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.12
```

What is the meaning of those conflicts? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Miniconda System Requirements Not Met

Most of the conflicts are superfluous. The key ones are right at the end: all those packages require `glibc >= 2.17` and your system (i.e., OS) only has GLIBC 2.12. So, we're talking CentOS 6 or similar RHEL, and this is a known issue that makes the newer Miniconda builds uninstallable for you. If you're deadset on Miniconda, you'll have to hit up the archive for an old version, [as suggested on the install page (which, BTW, notes CentOS 7+)](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#system-requirements). Unfortunately, I don't know which Miniconda version was the last to support GLIBC 2.12.

### Alternative: Try Mambaforge

Fortunately, most of Conda Forge continues to build on COS6 images, so try out [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) instead of Miniconda. **I highly recommend [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge).**

And yes, testing on the `centos6` Docker image, the latest Mambaforge installs and runs just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to go back to Miniconda V4.2.12 to get something working but packages such as cartopy were missing. Then, I tried Mamba, and it works like a charm! I was able to get the last conda version (4.10.3) and all packages I needed.

Comment: Question: Sometimes, I create environments using *conda* instead of *mamba* (I guess there is no difference, is that so?). When using *conda*, I get a message asking to update conda to latest version. Can I do this safely? Is it recommended to keep conda updated when using mamba? Should *mamba* be updated too (how?)? Thanks.

Comment: @TVG there can be differences in the solve results (since they use different SAT solvers), but they both still make valid (interoperable) Conda environments. Yes, Conda should be kept up-to-date. I usually check both for updates with `mamba update -n base mamba conda`.