# Conda installation works but I have problems with conda init

Tags: conda

I am installing miniconda on a hpc cluster. I used the following commands:

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

The installation seems to have worked although there are a few warnings about package conflicts. I've pasted the first few lines here:

```
PREFIX=/home/users/nus/e0470749/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package tk conflicts for:
pyopenssl==20.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
chardet==4.0.0=py39h06a4308_1003 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
pycosat==0.6.3=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
cryptography==3.4.7=py39hd23ed53_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
ruamel_yaml==0.15.100=py39h27cfd23_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
setuptools==52.0.0=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
tk==8.6.10=hbc83047_0
pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
conda-package-handling==1.7.3=py39h27cfd23_1 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
python==3.9.5=h12debd9_4 -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
cffi==1.14.6=py39h400218f_0 -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> tk[version='>=8.6.10,<8.7.0a0']
```

After the installation, I check the contents of `~/miniconda3` which looks like this:

```
10201 Jul 15 23:34 LICENSE.txt
4096 Dec  9 15:01 conda-meta
15215208 Dec  9 15:00 conda.exe
16384 Dec  9 15:01 pkgs
940 Jul 15 23:40 postconda.tar.bz2
```

This looks weird as I have never seen a `conda.exe` during previous miniconda installations. However, the conda installation seems to work. Running `~/miniconda3/conda.exe` produces the help message. I proceed to create an environment by running `~/miniconda3/conda.exe create -n test_env` which works.

However, I cannot activate the `test_env` environment. I next try to run `~/miniconda3/conda.exe init bash` resulting in this error message:

```
WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: /home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
      File "site-packages/conda/cli/main_init.py", line 50, in execute
      File "site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 121, in initialize
      File "site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 687, in run_plan_elevated
      File "site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 105, in subprocess_call
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['sudo', '/home/users/nus/e0470749/miniconda3/conda.exe', '-m', 'conda.core.initialize']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

`$ miniconda3/conda.exe init bash`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z
                  MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man/en:/usr/s
                          hare/man:/cm/local/apps/environment-modules/current/share/man:/opt/pbs
                          /share/man:/cm/local/apps/environment-
                          modules/current/share/man:/opt/pbs/share/man
               MODULEPATH=/cm/shared/modules/tools:/cm/shared/modules/interpreters:/cm/shared/mo
                          dules/bio:/cm/shared/modules/chem:/cm/shared/modules/earth:/cm/shared/
                          modules/engineering:/cm/shared/modules/dev-
                          intel:/cm/shared/modules/dev-gnu:/cm/shared/modules/dev-gpu:/cm/shared
                          /modules/dev:/cm/shared/modules/sys:/cm/shared/modules/dev-java
                     PATH=/tmp/_MEICzGwWY/bin:/app/pbs/bin:/tmp/_MEI3dVYpn/bin:/app/pbs/bin:/app
                          /pbs/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local
                          /sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/ibutils/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/pbs/bin:/h
                          ome/users/nus/e0470749/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/pbs/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=/home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z/certifi/cacert.pem

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/users/nus/e0470749/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.9.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __glibc=2.12=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z/pkgs
                          /home/users/nus/e0470749/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/users/nus/e0470749/.conda/envs
                          /home/users/nus/e0470749/TMPconda/_MEIs8OO7Z/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.0 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Linux/2.6.32-754.14.2.el6.x86_64 rhel/6.10 glibc/2.12
                UID:GID : 26101:26101
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

I saw online that there may be an issue with the `TMP` directory so I also tried to install by running `TMP=~/TMPconda bash Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-x86_64.sh` but this also results in the same error when running conda init. I have also tried installing with python 3.7 and 3.8 versions.

I have never encountered this error on my previous miniconda installations before. I think this is specific to the cluster I am using. Does anyone have advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Why is `sudo` being used? That should really only be for sys admins; end-users should almost always be doing user-level installation with no elevated privileges.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am on Linux.
This is the output of lsb_release -a:  
LSB Version: :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch  
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer  
Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
Release: 6.10  
Codename: Santiago

Comment: @merv I am not too sure either why sudo is in the subprocess commands. I just noticed after you pointed it out

Comment: Although it’s not included in the part of the error report shown here, I’d guess this is a GLIBC issue. That is, this is an old OS (reports GLIBC=2.12), but the package builds on the defaults channel require `glibc>=2.17`. If that is the issue, then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69378698/570918