# How to crate conda environment with GLIBC > 2.12 in HPC

Tags: conda, glibc, hpc

I am working within HPC where I have no root privileges. The latest version of GLIBC in the HPC is 2.12 where for many applications GLIBC>2.14 is required. I need to install an application that works within a conda  environment and require GLIBC>2.12. Is there a way to install GLIBC>2.12 within conda environment (using environment.yml) that will make GLIBC available to the apps installed in this environment?
I installed libc2.17 into the environment using:

```
conda install -c fridh glibc
```

while the conda environment was activated, but is resulted in:

> Segmentation fault

while trying to run the application.
Thank you.

Comment: Um...don't do that (install packages from rando user channels). Just use the **conda-forge** channel. Conda Forge continued building on CentOS 6 images up until very recently, so most Linux builds are available for GLIBC=2.12. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69386320/570918. Otherwise, request IT update your systems - it's their job to provide reasonable service.